# How can I render a html page using spark and MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I'm trying to render a plain html view using Spark and MVC but I obtain the following error:

```
The view 'Principal.html' or its master could not be found. The following locations were searched: 
~/Views/Site/Principal.html.aspx 
~/Views/Site/Principal.html.ascx 
~/Views/Shared/Principal.html.aspx 
~/Views/Shared/Principal.html.ascx 
Site\Principal.html.spark 
Shared\Principal.html.spark
```

In my controller i have:

```
 public ViewResult Principal()
   { 
      return View("Principal.html");
   }
```

I register the spark engina in my Global.asax, Start method

```
protected override void Start()
{
    ...
    RegisterViewEngine(ViewEngines.Engines, RouteTable.Routes);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);            
}

 private void RegisterViewEngine(ViewEngineCollection engines, RouteCollection routes)
 {
    SparkViewFactory engine = new SparkViewFactory();            
    RegisterFactory.DefaultRegister(IoCService.MyContainer, engine, routes);
    engines.Add(engine);
 }
```

How can I indicate that the page to render is html (Principal.html) and NOT spark extension?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it static html? If so, could you just redirect to it?

Comment: Yes, it's static html and it's the initial page of the site. But in because of my proyect configuration I need to render the page through the controller...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you rename `Principal.html` to `Principal.spark` or `Principal.html.spark` that should fix it.

Spark doesn't know that it should be looking for `.html` files to render. I wouldn't recommend telling Spark to handle all `.html` files, but if you really want to, then you can implement your own [Custom `IDescriptorFilter`implementation](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/viewlocations) to change the way that Spark locates views - but like I said, I wouldn't recommend it - I woud rather just rename `.html` files to `.spark` that you want Spark to pick up

Is there a reason you cannot rename your html file extensions?